# Initialize a static structure

Tags: c++, struct, file-descriptor

In

A.hh

```
class A{    
private:
    static struct pollfd fds[2];
}
```

How should I initialize the structure in the A.cpp file?

Comment: Why do you need global data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pollfd` contains two integer elements, you could do:

```
struct pollfd A::fds[2] = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```